Swift data race with AppKit MPMediaItemArtwork function
Consider the code below. It uses the AppKit (macOS) MPMediaItemArtwork function to set the artwork in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.
During runtime, when compiled with Swift 6, this gives the warning:
warning: data race detected: @MainActor function at MPMediaItemArtwork/ContentView.swift:22 was not called on the main thread

It seems that the requestHandler is not called on the main thread. Adding @MainActor in doesn't seem to make any difference. I may be a little rusty on the Objective-C side, but I can't figure out how to return the image on the main thread as it won't let me use a Task with a return value, as it doesn't support concurrency.
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .padding()
            .task {
                await MainActor.run {
                    let nowPlayingInfoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
                    var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
                    let image = NSImage(named: "image")!
                    // warning: data race detected: @MainActor function at MPMediaItemArtwork/ContentView.swift:22 was not called on the main thread
                    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { _ in
                        // Not on main thread here!
                        return image
                    })
                    
                    nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
                }
            }
    }
}

Here is a version I have updated to use async/await, however it still gives the same error on the same line:
extension MPMediaItemArtwork: @unchecked Swift.Sendable {
    
    @MainActor
    static func with(image: NSImage) async -> MPMediaItemArtwork {
        await withCheckedContinuation { [image] continuation in
            continuation.resume(returning: MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { [image] _ in
                return image
            })
        }
    }
}

.task {
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = await MPMediaItemArtwork.with(image: image)
}


I’ve been using async/await for years. I think the problem here is that Apples API controls which thread it’s run on, and it’s not the main thread.

The error only appears when using Swift 6

I have updated the question with my attempt at using checked continuation, but it still gives the same error.

The completion block is used in the init so it is more like a builder. The image returned in the completion block, isn't the actual result returned from the init.

The completion is an input rather than an output

Actually, yes you are right, You need an AsyncStream too since technically you are returning 2 things

Yeah this is weird one

Yes, thank you for looking. I've tried all sorts and starting to think only Apple can fix this by internally running the completion block on the main thread. I've just checked and it's the same in the iOS version too.

I posted some code, give it a try and let me know

It turns out there is an easy fix here. Simply marking the completion handler as @Sendable.
let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { @Sendable _ in
    return image
})

I'm still confused as to why there was no compiler warning or error here, but hopefully that's something Apple can/will fix.

Try this, it is a AsyncStream so it will return both values separately
@preconcurrency import MediaPlayer

extension MPMediaItemArtwork {
    static func with(image: NSImage) -> AsyncStream<ArtworkReturn> {
        return .init { streamContinuation in
            let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { (size) -> NSImage in
                defer{
                    streamContinuation.yield(.size(size))
                    streamContinuation.finish()
                }
                return image
            }
            
            streamContinuation.yield(.artwork(artwork))
        }
        
    }
    
    enum ArtworkReturn:Sendable {
        case artwork(MPMediaItemArtwork)
        case size(CGSize)
    }
}

I don't have a project setup but it should work. Usage would look something like
    .task {
        let stream = MPMediaItemArtwork.with(image: .init())
        for await result in stream {
            switch result {
            case .artwork(let mPMediaItemArtwork):
                //Do something with the artwork
                break
            case .size(let cGSize):
                //Do something with the size
                break
            }
        }
        print("Received both artwork and size")
    }


Besides some Sendable errors (which I can fix with @unchecked Sendable), it is giving an error Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter; later accesses could race on the let task = Task { line.

@Darren lol, that is a new one. I am not getting that one. Try using @preconcurrency at the import instead of @unchecked Sendable

@Darren I added another set of code

Ok, it compiles and runs, however the code remains in a loop awaiting the stream, so the final print is never printed. In fact, it seems the code block in the MPMediaItemArtwork continuation is never called!

@Darren get rid of the defer and move the finish to the line after the artwork yield. I dont really like it but it is a way to "resume" without waiting for the block. IDK what happens if the block is eventually called. Also it feels wrong since technically it is like continuation.resume I would definitely submit to Apple.

I'm thinking that as the block isn't actually being called, it will not have an image as it's the block that builds and returns the image to be used byMPMediaItemArtwork.

@Darren yeah, the more I think about it the alternative of finishing after artwork yield is a bad idea. The NSImage is basically being retained for as long as the artwork is being used. The requestHandler might even get called multiple times. It is more of an “image resized” block. That is the data race. The image can be used at any time.

I shall file a bug report with Apple. At the moment it is just showing the warning without crashing.

Spoke to soon. After updating to iOS 18, this is now a crash :(

@Darren I think this has been a bug since release. I dont think it makes sense to hold on to an NSImage for the lifetime of a MPMediaItemArtwork. Maybe review any new documentation see if there is an alternative. This seems like something that would have been caught a long time ago

So the answer here was to mark the completion block as @Sendable https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764874?answerId=810243022#810243022
